# How to position a cover image in the background?

Tags: html, css

I've placed an image in the background of my div with this code:

```
background: url(../images/cover-image.jpg) no-repeat 50% 100% fixed;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
height: 30rem;
```

But my problem now is, that I want to move the visible part of the image in the div. The Bottom of the picture should be at the bottom of the div, but I can change everything in the `background:` (`center bottom`, `50% 100%` etc.) statement, nothing happens.

Can anybody give me a hint?

Comment: Its hard to position a background image without any HTML.

Comment: have you tried using background-size:contain?

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
background-position: center bottom;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the other styling in you 'background' deceleration and just put:

```
background-position:bottom;
```

see the fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/xerf3z5j/

Answer (score 0):

As one line, this would be:

`background: transparent url(../images/cover-image.jpg) center bottom / cover no-repeat fixed;`

Comment: I think the combination of fixed and bottom is the problem, but why?

Answer (score -1):

background-size: cover means that the background image will always take the full width and height of your div.

Should work if you remove those parts:

```
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
 -o-background-size: cover;
 background-size: cover;
```

Comment: Any reason for downvoting? Would be nice if the user would leave a comment for the reason ;-)